# How to use svg names in ConTeXt?

Tags: color, context

ConTeXt provides multiple color modules which contain predefined colors. Among those distributed in TeX Live are X11 color and some others, but the svg names, which have become more common these days, are not there yet.

So how may I use something like:

```
\setupcolors  [state=start]
\usecolors    [svg]
\starttext
    \color[lavenderblush]{Text}
\stoptext
```

Comment: What is the difference between `X11` colors and `SVG` colors. At first glance, they appear to be the same. Wikipedia suggests that only a [few colors are different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names#Clashes_between_web_and_X11_colors_in_the_CSS_color_scheme)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer contains two alternative sources for the same colors (svg names). The files are formatted as modules and the easiest solution is to save one of those implementations as `colo-imp-svg.mkiv` in your working directory and then use `\usecolors [svg]`.

## Alternative 1 (RGB, from official w3c site)

```
%D \module
%D   [file=colo-imp-svg,
%D    version=2018.09.17,
%D    title=\CONTEXT\ Color Macros,
%D    subtitle=SVG,
%D    author=TeXnician]
%C

%D SVG named colors from https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords

\startprotectedcolors

\definecolor [aliceblue]            [r=0.941176, g=0.972549, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [antiquewhite]         [r=0.980392, g=0.921569, b=0.843137] 
\definecolor [aqua]                 [r=0.000000, g=1.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [aquamarine]           [r=0.498039, g=1.000000, b=0.831373] 
\definecolor [azure]                [r=0.941176, g=1.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [beige]                [r=0.960784, g=0.960784, b=0.862745] 
\definecolor [bisque]               [r=1.000000, g=0.894118, b=0.768627] 
\definecolor [black]                [r=0.000000, g=0.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [blanchedalmond]       [r=1.000000, g=0.921569, b=0.803922] 
\definecolor [blue]                 [r=0.000000, g=0.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [blueviolet]           [r=0.541176, g=0.168627, b=0.886275] 
\definecolor [brown]                [r=0.647059, g=0.164706, b=0.164706] 
\definecolor [burlywood]            [r=0.870588, g=0.721569, b=0.529412] 
\definecolor [cadetblue]            [r=0.372549, g=0.619608, b=0.627451] 
\definecolor [chartreuse]           [r=0.498039, g=1.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [chocolate]            [r=0.823529, g=0.411765, b=0.117647] 
\definecolor [coral]                [r=1.000000, g=0.498039, b=0.313726] 
\definecolor [cornflowerblue]       [r=0.392157, g=0.584314, b=0.929412] 
\definecolor [cornsilk]             [r=1.000000, g=0.972549, b=0.862745] 
\definecolor [crimson]              [r=0.862745, g=0.078431, b=0.235294] 
\definecolor [cyan]                 [r=0.000000, g=1.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [darkblue]             [r=0.000000, g=0.000000, b=0.545098] 
\definecolor [darkcyan]             [r=0.000000, g=0.545098, b=0.545098] 
\definecolor [darkgoldenrod]        [r=0.721569, g=0.525490, b=0.043137] 
\definecolor [darkgray]             [r=0.662745, g=0.662745, b=0.662745] 
\definecolor [darkgreen]            [r=0.000000, g=0.392157, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [darkgrey]             [r=0.662745, g=0.662745, b=0.662745] 
\definecolor [darkkhaki]            [r=0.741176, g=0.717647, b=0.419608] 
\definecolor [darkmagenta]          [r=0.545098, g=0.000000, b=0.545098] 
\definecolor [darkolivegreen]       [r=0.333333, g=0.419608, b=0.184314] 
\definecolor [darkorange]           [r=1.000000, g=0.549020, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [darkorchid]           [r=0.600000, g=0.196078, b=0.800000] 
\definecolor [darkred]              [r=0.545098, g=0.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [darksalmon]           [r=0.913725, g=0.588235, b=0.478431] 
\definecolor [darkseagreen]         [r=0.560784, g=0.737255, b=0.560784] 
\definecolor [darkslateblue]        [r=0.282353, g=0.239216, b=0.545098] 
\definecolor [darkslategray]        [r=0.184314, g=0.309804, b=0.309804] 
\definecolor [darkslategrey]        [r=0.184314, g=0.309804, b=0.309804] 
\definecolor [darkturquoise]        [r=0.000000, g=0.807843, b=0.819608] 
\definecolor [darkviolet]           [r=0.580392, g=0.000000, b=0.827451] 
\definecolor [deeppink]             [r=1.000000, g=0.078431, b=0.576471] 
\definecolor [deepskyblue]          [r=0.000000, g=0.749020, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [dimgray]              [r=0.411765, g=0.411765, b=0.411765] 
\definecolor [dimgrey]              [r=0.411765, g=0.411765, b=0.411765] 
\definecolor [dodgerblue]           [r=0.117647, g=0.564706, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [firebrick]            [r=0.698039, g=0.133333, b=0.133333] 
\definecolor [floralwhite]          [r=1.000000, g=0.980392, b=0.941176] 
\definecolor [forestgreen]          [r=0.133333, g=0.545098, b=0.133333] 
\definecolor [fuchsia]              [r=1.000000, g=0.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [gainsboro]            [r=0.862745, g=0.862745, b=0.862745] 
\definecolor [ghostwhite]           [r=0.972549, g=0.972549, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [gold]                 [r=1.000000, g=0.843137, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [goldenrod]            [r=0.854902, g=0.647059, b=0.125490] 
\definecolor [gray]                 [r=0.501961, g=0.501961, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [grey]                 [r=0.501961, g=0.501961, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [green]                [r=0.000000, g=0.501961, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [greenyellow]          [r=0.678431, g=1.000000, b=0.184314] 
\definecolor [honeydew]             [r=0.941176, g=1.000000, b=0.941176] 
\definecolor [hotpink]              [r=1.000000, g=0.411765, b=0.705882] 
\definecolor [indianred]            [r=0.803922, g=0.360784, b=0.360784] 
\definecolor [indigo]               [r=0.294118, g=0.000000, b=0.509804] 
\definecolor [ivory]                [r=1.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.941176] 
\definecolor [khaki]                [r=0.941176, g=0.901961, b=0.549020] 
\definecolor [lavender]             [r=0.901961, g=0.901961, b=0.980392] 
\definecolor [lavenderblush]        [r=1.000000, g=0.941176, b=0.960784] 
\definecolor [lawngreen]            [r=0.486275, g=0.988235, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [lemonchiffon]         [r=1.000000, g=0.980392, b=0.803922] 
\definecolor [lightblue]            [r=0.678431, g=0.847059, b=0.901961] 
\definecolor [lightcoral]           [r=0.941176, g=0.501961, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [lightcyan]            [r=0.878431, g=1.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [lightgoldenrodyellow] [r=0.980392, g=0.980392, b=0.823529] 
\definecolor [lightgray]            [r=0.827451, g=0.827451, b=0.827451] 
\definecolor [lightgreen]           [r=0.564706, g=0.933333, b=0.564706] 
\definecolor [lightgrey]            [r=0.827451, g=0.827451, b=0.827451] 
\definecolor [lightpink]            [r=1.000000, g=0.713726, b=0.756863] 
\definecolor [lightsalmon]          [r=1.000000, g=0.627451, b=0.478431] 
\definecolor [lightseagreen]        [r=0.125490, g=0.698039, b=0.666667] 
\definecolor [lightskyblue]         [r=0.529412, g=0.807843, b=0.980392] 
\definecolor [lightslategray]       [r=0.466667, g=0.533333, b=0.600000] 
\definecolor [lightslategrey]       [r=0.466667, g=0.533333, b=0.600000] 
\definecolor [lightsteelblue]       [r=0.690196, g=0.768627, b=0.870588] 
\definecolor [lightyellow]          [r=1.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.878431] 
\definecolor [lime]                 [r=0.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [limegreen]            [r=0.196078, g=0.803922, b=0.196078] 
\definecolor [linen]                [r=0.980392, g=0.941176, b=0.901961] 
\definecolor [magenta]              [r=1.000000, g=0.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [maroon]               [r=0.501961, g=0.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [mediumaquamarine]     [r=0.400000, g=0.803922, b=0.666667] 
\definecolor [mediumblue]           [r=0.000000, g=0.000000, b=0.803922] 
\definecolor [mediumorchid]         [r=0.729412, g=0.333333, b=0.827451] 
\definecolor [mediumpurple]         [r=0.576471, g=0.439216, b=0.858824] 
\definecolor [mediumseagreen]       [r=0.235294, g=0.701961, b=0.443137] 
\definecolor [mediumslateblue]      [r=0.482353, g=0.407843, b=0.933333] 
\definecolor [mediumspringgreen]    [r=0.000000, g=0.980392, b=0.603922] 
\definecolor [mediumturquoise]      [r=0.282353, g=0.819608, b=0.800000] 
\definecolor [mediumvioletred]      [r=0.780392, g=0.082353, b=0.521569] 
\definecolor [midnightblue]         [r=0.098039, g=0.098039, b=0.439216] 
\definecolor [mintcream]            [r=0.960784, g=1.000000, b=0.980392] 
\definecolor [mistyrose]            [r=1.000000, g=0.894118, b=0.882353] 
\definecolor [moccasin]             [r=1.000000, g=0.894118, b=0.709804] 
\definecolor [navajowhite]          [r=1.000000, g=0.870588, b=0.678431] 
\definecolor [navy]                 [r=0.000000, g=0.000000, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [oldlace]              [r=0.992157, g=0.960784, b=0.901961] 
\definecolor [olive]                [r=0.501961, g=0.501961, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [olivedrab]            [r=0.419608, g=0.556863, b=0.137255] 
\definecolor [orange]               [r=1.000000, g=0.647059, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [orangered]            [r=1.000000, g=0.270588, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [orchid]               [r=0.854902, g=0.439216, b=0.839216] 
\definecolor [palegoldenrod]        [r=0.933333, g=0.909804, b=0.666667] 
\definecolor [palegreen]            [r=0.596078, g=0.984314, b=0.596078] 
\definecolor [paleturquoise]        [r=0.686275, g=0.933333, b=0.933333] 
\definecolor [palevioletred]        [r=0.858824, g=0.439216, b=0.576471] 
\definecolor [papayawhip]           [r=1.000000, g=0.937255, b=0.835294] 
\definecolor [peachpuff]            [r=1.000000, g=0.854902, b=0.725490] 
\definecolor [peru]                 [r=0.803922, g=0.521569, b=0.247059] 
\definecolor [pink]                 [r=1.000000, g=0.752941, b=0.796078] 
\definecolor [plum]                 [r=0.866667, g=0.627451, b=0.866667] 
\definecolor [powderblue]           [r=0.690196, g=0.878431, b=0.901961] 
\definecolor [purple]               [r=0.501961, g=0.000000, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [red]                  [r=1.000000, g=0.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [rosybrown]            [r=0.737255, g=0.560784, b=0.560784] 
\definecolor [royalblue]            [r=0.254902, g=0.411765, b=0.882353] 
\definecolor [saddlebrown]          [r=0.545098, g=0.270588, b=0.074510] 
\definecolor [salmon]               [r=0.980392, g=0.501961, b=0.447059] 
\definecolor [sandybrown]           [r=0.956863, g=0.643137, b=0.376471] 
\definecolor [seagreen]             [r=0.180392, g=0.545098, b=0.341176] 
\definecolor [seashell]             [r=1.000000, g=0.960784, b=0.933333] 
\definecolor [sienna]               [r=0.627451, g=0.321569, b=0.176471] 
\definecolor [silver]               [r=0.752941, g=0.752941, b=0.752941] 
\definecolor [skyblue]              [r=0.529412, g=0.807843, b=0.921569] 
\definecolor [slateblue]            [r=0.415686, g=0.352941, b=0.803922] 
\definecolor [slategray]            [r=0.439216, g=0.501961, b=0.564706] 
\definecolor [slategrey]            [r=0.439216, g=0.501961, b=0.564706] 
\definecolor [snow]                 [r=1.000000, g=0.980392, b=0.980392] 
\definecolor [springgreen]          [r=0.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.498039] 
\definecolor [steelblue]            [r=0.274510, g=0.509804, b=0.705882] 
\definecolor [tan]                  [r=0.823529, g=0.705882, b=0.549020] 
\definecolor [teal]                 [r=0.000000, g=0.501961, b=0.501961] 
\definecolor [thistle]              [r=0.847059, g=0.749020, b=0.847059] 
\definecolor [tomato]               [r=1.000000, g=0.388235, b=0.278431] 
\definecolor [turquoise]            [r=0.250980, g=0.878431, b=0.815686] 
\definecolor [violet]               [r=0.933333, g=0.509804, b=0.933333] 
\definecolor [wheat]                [r=0.960784, g=0.870588, b=0.701961] 
\definecolor [white]                [r=1.000000, g=1.000000, b=1.000000] 
\definecolor [whitesmoke]           [r=0.960784, g=0.960784, b=0.960784] 
\definecolor [yellow]               [r=1.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.000000] 
\definecolor [yellowgreen]          [r=0.603922, g=0.803922, b=0.196078] 

\stopprotectedcolors

\endinput
```

## Alternative 2 (Hex, manually converted from w3c rgb)

```
%D \module
%D   [file=colo-imp-svg,
%D    version=2018.09.23,
%D    title=\CONTEXT\ Color Macros,
%D    subtitle=SVG,
%D    author=TeXnician]
%C

%D SVG named colors from https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords
%D manually converted to hex colors

\startprotectedcolors

\definecolor [aliceblue]            [h=F0F8FF] 
\definecolor [antiquewhite]         [h=FAEBD7] 
\definecolor [aqua]                 [h=00FFFF] 
\definecolor [aquamarine]           [h=7FFFD4] 
\definecolor [azure]                [h=F0FFFF] 
\definecolor [beige]                [h=F5F5DC] 
\definecolor [bisque]               [h=FFE4C4] 
\definecolor [black]                [h=000000] 
\definecolor [blanchedalmond]       [h=FFEBCD] 
\definecolor [blue]                 [h=0000FF] 
\definecolor [blueviolet]           [h=8A2BE2] 
\definecolor [brown]                [h=A52A2A] 
\definecolor [burlywood]            [h=DEB887] 
\definecolor [cadetblue]            [h=5F9EA0] 
\definecolor [chartreuse]           [h=7FFF00] 
\definecolor [chocolate]            [h=D2691E] 
\definecolor [coral]                [h=FF7F50] 
\definecolor [cornflowerblue]       [h=6495ED] 
\definecolor [cornsilk]             [h=FFF8DC] 
\definecolor [crimson]              [h=DC143C] 
\definecolor [cyan]                 [h=00FFFF] 
\definecolor [darkblue]             [h=00008B] 
\definecolor [darkcyan]             [h=008B8B] 
\definecolor [darkgoldenrod]        [h=B8860B] 
\definecolor [darkgray]             [h=A9A9A9] 
\definecolor [darkgreen]            [h=006400] 
\definecolor [darkgrey]             [h=A9A9A9] 
\definecolor [darkkhaki]            [h=BDB76B] 
\definecolor [darkmagenta]          [h=8B008B] 
\definecolor [darkolivegreen]       [h=556B2F] 
\definecolor [darkorange]           [h=FF8C00] 
\definecolor [darkorchid]           [h=9932CC] 
\definecolor [darkred]              [h=8B0000] 
\definecolor [darksalmon]           [h=E9967A] 
\definecolor [darkseagreen]         [h=8FBC8F] 
\definecolor [darkslateblue]        [h=483D8B] 
\definecolor [darkslategray]        [h=2F4F4F] 
\definecolor [darkslategrey]        [h=2F4F4F] 
\definecolor [darkturquoise]        [h=00CED1] 
\definecolor [darkviolet]           [h=9400D3] 
\definecolor [deeppink]             [h=FF1493] 
\definecolor [deepskyblue]          [h=00BFFF] 
\definecolor [dimgray]              [h=696969] 
\definecolor [dimgrey]              [h=696969] 
\definecolor [dodgerblue]           [h=1E90FF] 
\definecolor [firebrick]            [h=B22222] 
\definecolor [floralwhite]          [h=FFFAF0] 
\definecolor [forestgreen]          [h=228B22] 
\definecolor [fuchsia]              [h=FF00FF] 
\definecolor [gainsboro]            [h=DCDCDC] 
\definecolor [ghostwhite]           [h=F8F8FF] 
\definecolor [gold]                 [h=FFD700] 
\definecolor [goldenrod]            [h=DAA520] 
\definecolor [gray]                 [h=808080] 
\definecolor [grey]                 [h=808080] 
\definecolor [green]                [h=008000] 
\definecolor [greenyellow]          [h=ADFF2F] 
\definecolor [honeydew]             [h=F0FFF0] 
\definecolor [hotpink]              [h=FF69B4] 
\definecolor [indianred]            [h=CD5C5C] 
\definecolor [indigo]               [h=4B0082] 
\definecolor [ivory]                [h=FFFFF0] 
\definecolor [khaki]                [h=F0E68C] 
\definecolor [lavender]             [h=E6E6FA] 
\definecolor [lavenderblush]        [h=FFF0F5] 
\definecolor [lawngreen]            [h=7CFC00] 
\definecolor [lemonchiffon]         [h=FFFACD] 
\definecolor [lightblue]            [h=ADD8E6] 
\definecolor [lightcoral]           [h=F08080] 
\definecolor [lightcyan]            [h=E0FFFF] 
\definecolor [lightgoldenrodyellow] [h=FAFAD2] 
\definecolor [lightgray]            [h=D3D3D3] 
\definecolor [lightgreen]           [h=90EE90] 
\definecolor [lightgrey]            [h=D3D3D3] 
\definecolor [lightpink]            [h=FFB6C1] 
\definecolor [lightsalmon]          [h=FFA07A] 
\definecolor [lightseagreen]        [h=20B2AA] 
\definecolor [lightskyblue]         [h=87CEFA] 
\definecolor [lightslategray]       [h=778899] 
\definecolor [lightslategrey]       [h=778899] 
\definecolor [lightsteelblue]       [h=B0C4DE] 
\definecolor [lightyellow]          [h=FFFFE0] 
\definecolor [lime]                 [h=00FF00] 
\definecolor [limegreen]            [h=32CD32] 
\definecolor [linen]                [h=FAF0E6] 
\definecolor [magenta]              [h=FF00FF] 
\definecolor [maroon]               [h=800000] 
\definecolor [mediumaquamarine]     [h=66CDAA] 
\definecolor [mediumblue]           [h=0000CD] 
\definecolor [mediumorchid]         [h=BA55D3] 
\definecolor [mediumpurple]         [h=9370DB] 
\definecolor [mediumseagreen]       [h=3CB371] 
\definecolor [mediumslateblue]      [h=7B68EE] 
\definecolor [mediumspringgreen]    [h=00FA9A] 
\definecolor [mediumturquoise]      [h=48D1CC] 
\definecolor [mediumvioletred]      [h=C71585] 
\definecolor [midnightblue]         [h=191970] 
\definecolor [mintcream]            [h=F5FFFA] 
\definecolor [mistyrose]            [h=FFE4E1] 
\definecolor [moccasin]             [h=FFE4B5] 
\definecolor [navajowhite]          [h=FFDEAD] 
\definecolor [navy]                 [h=000080] 
\definecolor [oldlace]              [h=FDF5E6] 
\definecolor [olive]                [h=808000] 
\definecolor [olivedrab]            [h=6B8E23] 
\definecolor [orange]               [h=FFA500] 
\definecolor [orangered]            [h=FF4500] 
\definecolor [orchid]               [h=DA70D6] 
\definecolor [palegoldenrod]        [h=EEE8AA] 
\definecolor [palegreen]            [h=98FB98] 
\definecolor [paleturquoise]        [h=AFEEEE] 
\definecolor [palevioletred]        [h=DB7093] 
\definecolor [papayawhip]           [h=FFEFD5] 
\definecolor [peachpuff]            [h=FFDAB9] 
\definecolor [peru]                 [h=CD853F] 
\definecolor [pink]                 [h=FFC0CB] 
\definecolor [plum]                 [h=DDA0DD] 
\definecolor [powderblue]           [h=B0E0E6] 
\definecolor [purple]               [h=800080] 
\definecolor [red]                  [h=FF0000] 
\definecolor [rosybrown]            [h=BC8F8F] 
\definecolor [royalblue]            [h=4169E1] 
\definecolor [saddlebrown]          [h=8B4513] 
\definecolor [salmon]               [h=FA8072] 
\definecolor [sandybrown]           [h=F4A460] 
\definecolor [seagreen]             [h=2E8B57] 
\definecolor [seashell]             [h=FFF5EE] 
\definecolor [sienna]               [h=A0522D] 
\definecolor [silver]               [h=C0C0C0] 
\definecolor [skyblue]              [h=87CEEB] 
\definecolor [slateblue]            [h=6A5ACD] 
\definecolor [slategray]            [h=708090] 
\definecolor [slategrey]            [h=708090] 
\definecolor [snow]                 [h=FFFAFA] 
\definecolor [springgreen]          [h=00FF7F] 
\definecolor [steelblue]            [h=4682B4] 
\definecolor [tan]                  [h=D2B48C] 
\definecolor [teal]                 [h=008080] 
\definecolor [thistle]              [h=D8BFD8] 
\definecolor [tomato]               [h=FF6347] 
\definecolor [turquoise]            [h=40E0D0] 
\definecolor [violet]               [h=EE82EE] 
\definecolor [wheat]                [h=F5DEB3] 
\definecolor [white]                [h=FFFFFF] 
\definecolor [whitesmoke]           [h=F5F5F5] 
\definecolor [yellow]               [h=FFFF00] 
\definecolor [yellowgreen]          [h=9ACD32]

\stopprotectedcolors

\endinput
```

Comment: Just send this to Hans.  I'm sure he'll include it in the core.

Comment: @HenriMenke Where would I send this to? The Pragma company e-mail address?

Comment: `j <dot> hagen <at> xs4all <dot> nl`  That's the address by which he posts on the mailing list.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, I'll send it later today.

Comment: @TeXnician: You can also post to ntg-context@ntg.nl (the context mailing list) or dev-context@ntg.nl (context dev list).

Comment: Note that the color definitions are almost the same as in `colo-imp-xwi` and `colo-imp-x11`.

Comment: @Aditya If I recall correctly, svg color names are derived from x11 color names (with a few adjustments). But as I deal with automated input (which may contain all svg color names) I need to have the complete scheme and in `colo-imp-xwi` the grays are missing and in `colo-imp-x11` the greys.

Answer (score 4):

These colors are available in ConTeXt under the color scheme [`xwi`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/052a096e160508ddbbbfcbf1522eb8ddbfc3b1cd/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-xwi.mkiv) for (X-Windows). The note above the file says

```
%D I've forgotten where I got these definitions from, but maybe
%D they can be of use.
```

So, you can use

```
\usecolors    [xwi]
\starttext
    \color[lavenderblush]{Text}
\stoptext
```

Note that for MkIV, you don't need to include the line `\setupcolors[state=start]` because colors are enabled by default.

A very similar color scheme is available as [`x11`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/052a096e160508ddbbbfcbf1522eb8ddbfc3b1cd/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-x11.mkiv). The source says that these colors are taken from `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.

Another color scheme with svg colors is [`ema`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/052a096e160508ddbbbfcbf1522eb8ddbfc3b1cd/tex/context/base/mkiv/colo-imp-ema.mkiv) which contains "Emacs" colors from `/emacs/etc/rgb.txt`. This even contains a few variants of `lavenderblush`